# GNU libmicrohttpd with client TLS allows empty certificate

Tags: c++, c, ssl, httpserver, client-certificates

I am using GNU libmicrohttpd to establish HTTPS server. My requirement is that the server and the client both authenticate during the TLS handshake however what I observe is that even if the client sends empty certificate the connection is accepted.

in wireshark I see that the server requests certificate and the client sends certificate with len 0. How to make the microhttpd to not accept that case - the certificate must always be verified with the provided CA pem?

```
if(!(server_handle = MHD_start_daemon(flags, port, NULL, NULL, 
    &mhttpd_layer::access_handler_callback, callback_data,
                    // now, continue with the options
                    MHD_OPTION_NOTIFY_COMPLETED, &mhttpd_layer::request_completed_callback, l_callback_data,
                    MHD_OPTION_SOCK_ADDR, (sockaddr*) &(it->addr),
                    MHD_OPTION_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, it->conn_timeout,
                    MHD_OPTION_CONNECTION_LIMIT, it->conn_limit,
                    MHD_OPTION_PER_IP_CONNECTION_LIMIT, it->per_ip_conn_limit,
                    // HTTPS certificate options
                    MHD_OPTION_HTTPS_MEM_KEY, it->https_key_buff.data(),
                    MHD_OPTION_HTTPS_MEM_CERT, it->https_cert_buff.data(),
                    MHD_OPTION_HTTPS_MEM_TRUST, it->https_turst_ca_buff.data(),
                    MHD_OPTION_END)))
```

Maybe I should manually on the access callback retrieve the certificate as described by their tutorial (https://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/tutorial.html#Adding-a-layer-of-security) ? In this case why do I provide the CA - this doesn't seem the proper way to me?

Comment: Do you mean why do you have to provide MHD_start_daemon the CA if you're then going to validate the certificate yourself? I think it's part of the handshake: the server says 'I only accept client certs signed by this CA', so it needs the certificate even if it doesn't then do the verification itself. But I suspect it does do the verification at the moment, it just allows empty certificates as not authenticated and you probably just need to check for and reject that case (if there isn't a MHD flag you can set to get it to do that for you).

Comment: Thank you @Rup - I guess I probably just need to check indeed. Just wanted to be sure this is correct - i.e. I couldn't find a suitable flag